# C++ String insert iteration

Tags: c++, string

I have the string:

```
string str = "1234567890";

//Magic code

cout<<str<<endl;
```

Which i want to output: 12 34 56 78 90

I assume std has some neat feature/function to help solve this. How do I that in the most convenient way?

Comment: There's no magic solution, using a simple for loop is convenient I'd say.

Comment: Are those duplicate `5`s intended? That would probably change the correct answer a lot. i.e. do you want just to insert spaces between every 2 characters, or do you want to insert spaces at some magical junction, in this case, between adjacent odd and even numbers, while also stripping duplicate characters... Presumably the answer is the former.

Comment: What should happen if `str` contains an odd number of digits? Non-digits? Non-Graphical-characters? Spaces?

Comment: Then you start wondering about Unicode characters and realise C++ still doesn't have an official Unicode string class :| (protip: in the meantime, use `ustring` from `glibmm`)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::string::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) with a `for` loop could help you to insert spaces into an `std::string` very easely:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "1234567890";

    for(auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it += min<int>(str.end() - it, 2))
        it = (it != str.begin() ? str.insert(it, ' ') + 1 : it);

    cout << str << endl;
}
```

The `std::string::insert` returns an iterator pointing to the character inserted, therefore it has to be incremented to step over the inserted character.

Because `std::string` has a [random-access iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/) it can be incremented or decremented more than by one. The `min<int>(str.end() - it, 2)` ensures that the next step won't go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach. Define a function that inserts a given character `char_to_insert` into a given string `s` every `interval` characters, excluding beginning and end of string:

```
std::string insert_char(const std::string& s, char char_to_insert, size_t interval)
{
    // corner cases
    if (!interval || !s.length()) return s;

    // compute number of characters to insert
    auto number_of_chars_to_insert = (s.length()-1)/interval;

    // compute total length
    auto output_length = s.length() + number_of_chars_to_insert;

    // pre-allocate output string with all characters equal to char_to_insert
    std::string retval(output_length, char_to_insert);

    // cycle input string, keeping track of position in input and output strings
    size_t pos = 0, pos_in_input = 0;
    for (const auto& c : s)
    {
        // copy from input to output
        retval[pos++] = c;

        // advance in output every interval chars
        if ((++pos_in_input) % interval == 0)
            ++pos;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "1234567890";
    for (size_t i = 1; i != 5; ++i)
        std::cout << insert_char(s, ' ', i) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
12 34 56 78 90
123 456 789 0
1234 5678 90
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in to do what you want.
Instead, the most convenient solution is probably to iterate through the string and output pairs of digits as you go:

```
string str = "1234567890";
for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << *(it);
    if (++it != str.end()){
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or non-iterator version:

```
string str = "1234567890";
for (idx = 0; idx < str.length(); idx += 2){
    std::cout << str.substr(idx, 2) << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Both of these examples will have a trailing space on the line, but I've left it in to keep the examples simpler.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses in `*(it)`; `*it` is sufficient.

Comment: @PeteBecker ah yes, I was going to be 'clever' and mix in the iterator incrementation for the second character on the same line, then thought better of it.

Comment: When you stream a length-1-string, it's a waste. Use a `char` instead.